# Check tab from activity to fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJy24.png)

look like this  i am here using adapter class for non answerd tab , actully i'm need when we select radio button and click to next then tab will be selected as answerd 
here is non selected code 
1.**From adapter class**

```
 public View getSelectedTabView(int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.custom_tab_circle);
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.custom_tab_textView);
    //textView.setText(mfragmentTitlelist.get(position+1));
    //textView.setText(position);
    //textView.setText((CharSequence) fragmentList.get(position));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.append(position+1).toString();
    textView.setText(builder.toString());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_circle);
    // here is image will be transparent
    imageView.setAlpha(0.5f);


    //.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yellow));
    //ImageView tabImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.tabImageView);
    //imageView.setImageResource(mFragmentIconList.get(position));
    //imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.background_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    return view;
}
```

**2. now we call this code in Activity.java **

```
  highLightCurrentTab(position);


  private void highLightCurrentTab(int position) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
    assert tab != null;
    tab.setCustomView(null);
    tab.setCustomView(adapter.getSelectedTabView(position));
    /*tab.setCustomView(adapter.getPageTitle(position).charAt(position));*/

}
```

so help me out what to do for  when select a answer my tab image will be selected as answered ...
thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for listener to your tablayout;

```
  tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Also you can check is selected any radio button with this code;

```
if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
{
  // no radio buttons are checked
}

else
{
  // one of the radio buttons is checked
}
```